# How to remove blank from code

Tags: c++

I have coded this program and it works fine. I get the result I want but because we are using an old system to submit it, my code is rejected because it saying that the 3 last lines generate a blank of my code. Can someone please tell me where is the problem and how I can fix it? Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, row_nr;
    cin >> row_nr;
    if(row_nr > 1 && row_nr <= 30)
        for(i = 1; i <= row_nr; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < row_nr; j++)
            {
                cout << i + j * (row_nr);
                {
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean a space. That comes from here: `cout<<" ";` Either figure out that you've printed the last value and don't print a space after it, or print a space before every value but the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting a space after every value, so there is going to be a space at the end of each line. You should add a check so that you don't output a space after the last value of each line. It seems like you might have intended to do this, but forgot to write the if statement.

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <iomanip> why?
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int row_nr;
    cin >> row_nr;
    if(row_nr > 1 && row_nr <= 30)
        for(int i = 1; i <= row_nr; i++) //declare iterator variable in for loop statement
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < row_nr; j++)
            {
                cout << i + j * (row_nr);
                if(j < row_nr - 1) //you forgot this line
                {
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
            cout << '\n'; //endl flushes the buffer, unnecessary here
        }
    return 0;
}
```